# Summation of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\sqrt n}$

Tags: summation, closed-form

Is there a closed form for the following sum?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\sqrt n}$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha does not show an expression, so probably there is no closed form.

Comment: Various inverse symbolic calculators come up with nothing either.

Comment: Depends upon the meaning of "closed form"; for instance, one could probably add/subtract cosh(), sinh() and do some symmetry touch-up.

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\sqrt{x}}\,dx = 2$$ and the difference between the sum and the above integral can be estimated through Abel's or Euler-MacLaurin summation formulas.

Comment: Based on my answer to [1], we can write the answer as a more interesting sum
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{n}}=\frac{5}{2} - \sum_{s=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(1+\frac{s}{2})\zeta(1+\frac{s}{2})\sin(\frac{\pi s}{4})}{(-1)^s \pi(2\pi)^{s/2} \Gamma(s+1)}
$$


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287417/find-the-limiting-value-of-s-a-sqrt1a-sqrt2a-sqrt3a-sqrt4/2340926#2340926

Comment: [Also related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3637584).