# Analytic continuation of $\Phi(s)=\sum_{n \ge 1} e^{-n^s}$

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

(After 3 bounties I've also [posted on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/368647)).

While discussing [theta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function), I thought:

$\zeta(s)=\sum n^{-s}=1+2^{-s}+3^{-s}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$

and

$\Phi(s)=\sum e^{-n^s}=e^{-1}+e^{-2^s}+e^{-3^s}+\cdot\cdot\cdot $

> What is the analytic continuation of $\Phi(s)?$

User @reuns had an insightful point that maybe, $\sum_n (e^{-n^{-s}}-1)=\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \zeta(sk).$

If the sum were instead a product, then the analytic continuation would coincide with the analytic continuation of $\zeta(s).$

Comment: "$\Phi$ and $\zeta$ are congruent structures. What I mean by that is that I think $\Phi$ also has a critical strip, nontrivial zeros, euler product, functional equation, etc" doesn't make any sense. It seems not crazy to ask if your function may be the analytic continuation of $\sum_n (e^{-n^{-s}}-1)=\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \zeta(sk)$ wihch

is analytic on $\Bbb{C}^* - \cup 1/k$ (because $(s-1)\zeta(s) = O(e^{|s|})$)

Comment: @reuns maybe you can speak to my edit?

Comment: You should rename thisone into "analytic continuation of $\sum_{n\ge 1} e^{-n^s}$" and remove the remaining part. Did you try drawing $\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \zeta(-sk)$ and comparing ? As I said it seems obvious both functions are related.

Comment: but I thought you said that there's no point in asking about the analytical continuation!

Comment: I never said that. I said your other question was a duplicate and I was upset because you didn't mention my result : that $\sum_n (e^{-n^{-s}}-1)=\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \zeta(sk)$ is analytic away from the $1/k,k\ge 1$. And that asking for a functional equation doesn't make sense.

Comment: @reuns okay I understand now. I tried drawing $\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \zeta(-sk)$ and am comparing the two functions atm

Comment: @reuns: While $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ has order $1$, it is still not $O(e^{|s|})$ (more specifically, $|\zeta(1-2n)|$ grow superexponentially). Anyway your suggestion looks very promising.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is *currently* a partial answer, refining the idea given by @reuns.

---

The series $\Phi(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ e^{-n^s}$ converges iff $s>0$ is real. Using the [Cahen–Mellin integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#Cahen%E2%80%93Mellin_integral) $$e^{-x}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\Gamma(z)x^{-z}\,dz\qquad(x,c>0)$$ with $x=n^s$ and $c>1/s$, we get $$\Phi(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\Gamma(z)\zeta(sz)\,dz.$$

For $0<s<1$, the integrand tends to $0$ rapidly enough when $z\to\infty$ in the half-plane $\Re z\leqslant c$ and out of a neighborhood of the line $L=\{z : \Im z=0\wedge\Re z\leqslant 1/s\}$. This allows us to deform the path of integration, making it encircle $L$, and we see that $\Phi(s)$ is equal to the (infinite) sum of residues of the integrand at its poles (which are $z=1/s$ and $z=-n$ for nonnegative integers $n$). Computing these, we get $$\Phi(s)=\Gamma\left(1+\frac1s\right)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\zeta(-ns).$$

This series converges for *complex* $s\neq 0$ with $\Re s<1$ (at least; the singularities at $s=-1/n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ are removable), and gives the analytic continuation of $\Phi(s)$ in this region.

---

*The remaining question is whether we can extend this region further.*

Comment: I posted a remark in the parallel MO thread. Just thought you might be interested :-)

Comment: First thanks, I had my mind elsewhere so I'm just reading it a lot of days later so sorry about that, and also sorry because in those three expression you added you got me lost, not sure how the Stirling expression became that, then what happened to $|\zeta(1+ns)|$ and why $\tau$ must be the one satisfying that exactly, maybe I need to come back later if I ever get more math savvy. (I deleted what I asked previously as it seemed irrelevant now and was bloating the comments)