# Does this function come up anywhere in mathematics? $f(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\zeta(-ns)$

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, applications, elliptic-functions, analytic-continuation

I'm wondering if anyone knows if this function comes up anywhere in mathematics:

$$f(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\zeta(-ns)$$

where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann Zeta function.

I'm asking because it appeared for me as a term in an analytic continuation that I was doing. So I thought about just looking at this piece and trying to understand its properties.

The series I was working on continuing is:

$$ \Phi(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{{-n}^s} $$

and using the key fact:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{{-n}^s}-1)= f(s) $$

The analytic continuation valid for $\Re(s)<1$ is:

$$\Phi(s)=\Gamma\bigg(1+\frac{1}{s}\bigg)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\zeta(-ns)$$

with poles at $s=-\frac{1}{n}$ a non-isolated singularity at $s=0.$ The fact that the singularities of this function accumulate at a finite point may make working with this function awkward.

> Does $f(s)$ or $\Phi(s)$ come up anywhere, possibly in the theory of elliptic functions?

I asked my professor of geometry and another of analytic number theory and the geometry professor said he "knows about the last function $\Phi(s)$ but it's a long story." The analytic number theorist had not seen this function before.

I'm wondering if anyone else knows about this function and possible applications of it.

Comment: Originally appeared [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3637584).

Comment: For $\Re s <  - 1$, you can write it in terms of the [generalised Bessel function](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-38.1.257): $$
f(s) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\phi (s,0; - t^{ - s} )}}{{e^t  - 1}}\frac{{dt}}{t}} .
$$

Comment: Your question doesn't add anything compared to the previous ones. @metamorphy's [analytic continuation of $\sum_{n\ge 1} e^{-n^s}, s >0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3808724/276986) is as far as we can get,  quite worrying that you didn't link to it.

Comment: @reuns yes it adds something new. I'm asking about where this function shows up in mathematics and if there is a theory involving it. Just given the function by itself as an analytic continuation of the series is helpful but I'm wondering about a more general theory

Comment: @reuns I think $\varphi(s)$ is related to the theory of elliptic functions. Do you know about this?