# Solution verification. Extension of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to follow this argument but with a slight difference: [Continuation of series using Cahen-Mellin integral.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3808724/460999)

I start with $\Phi(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^s},$ which converges iff $s>0$ is real.

Applying the Mellin inversion theorem we have that:

$$e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{2K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}x^{-z}~dz$$

Where $K$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Then letting $x=e^{-n^{-s}}$ we have:

$$\Phi(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{2K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{zn^{-s}}\bigg)~dz$$

> Am I on the right track? How do I get to the solution?

Comment: Can you please give a reference where you found the initial inverse Mellin transform $e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{2K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}x^{-z}~dz$? In the second inverse Mellin transform I don't believe $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{z\,n^{-s}}$ converges.

Comment: @StevenClark yes, I don't think it converges but then what did I do wrong?

Comment: The Mellin Transform of e^(1/lnx) is $2K_1(2\sqrt(z))/\sqrt(z)$

Comment: or you just start by taking the inverse Mellin Transform of $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z-1)$ which is the $K_1$ and then take one more inverse Mellin Transform of the $K_1$

Comment: The inverse Mellin transform $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{2\,K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}x^{-z}\,dz=e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}$ is only valid for $0<x<1$. In other words $\int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}\,x^{z-1}\,dz=\frac{2\,K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}$ which is valid for $\Re(z)>0$, so $\frac{2\,K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}$ is the Mellin transform of $(\theta(x)-\theta(x-1))\,e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}$ versus the Mellin transform of $e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+Mellin+Transform+of+2BesselK%281%2C2sqrt%28z%29%29%2Fsqrt%28z%29

Comment: In Mathematica InverseMellinTransform[$\frac{2\,K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}$,z,x] generates the same result as WolframAlpha, but InverseMellinTransform[$\frac{2\,K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}$,z,x,GenerateConditions->True] clarifies the result is conditional for $0<x<1$. I also used Mathematica to obtain the integral result $\int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}\,x^{z-1}\,dz=\frac{2\,K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}$. Mathematica can't seem to evaluate MellinTransform[$e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}$,x,z].

Comment: In fact Mathematica indicates the Mellin Transform integral $\int_0^\infty e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}\,x^{z-1}\,dx=\frac{2\,K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}$ doesn't converge.

Comment: @StevenClark okay, so $0<x<1.$ and $\Re(z)>0.$

Comment: I think you mean $dx$ at the end of the integral

Comment: what impact does this have on the evaluation of the last integral $\Phi(s)$?

Comment: Yes I corrected it. I'm wondering if perhaps $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{z\,n^{-s}}$ converges in a distributional sense. For example the Fourier series for the Dirac comb converges in a distributional sense (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb#Fourier_series).

Comment: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{z\,n^{-s}}$ converges in a distributional sense, then one could perhaps use the distributional representation to evaluate the related inverse Mellin transform integral.

Comment: okay. the substitution $x=e^{-n^{-s}}$ is valid right?

Comment: Since your initial inverse Mellin transform integral is only valid for $0<x<1$, it seems to me any result you're able to obtain will also only be valid for $0<x<1$ instead of $x>0$ (which is better than nothing), but it's not obvious to me how to proceed with evaluation of the second inverse Mellin transform integral at this point.

Comment: from the link(in the post), we know the answer right? Is it arriving at that answer that's difficult?

Comment: Yes that's one formula, but I wonder if this question leads to another formula. I mentioned above the initial inverse Mellin transform is only valid for $0<x<1$. After thinking about it some more it seems to me the substitution $x=e^{-n^{-s}}$ leads to $0<e^{-n^{-s}}<1$ which is valid for all $s>0$ (since $n\in\mathbb{Z}\land n>0$), so perhaps the result of the second inverse Mellin transform would be valid for all $s>0$. It appears the formula from the answer in your initial question is valid for $0<\Re(s)<1$, so perhaps the approach here would result in a different formula.

Comment: can Mathematica evaluate the inverse Mellin transform of $e^{\frac{1}{\log(z)}}$?

Comment: No Mathematica gives up pretty much immediately as does Wolfram Alpha, but I'm not sure how $\mathcal{M}_x^{-1}\left[e^{\frac{1}{\log (x)}}\right](y)$ is related to this question.

Comment: @StevenClark If the substition is valid, then why would the integral not converge? What I'm saying is why did this approach work in the linked post but in this case there's no convergence of the integral?

Comment: Don't know how to help to your question, but I would like to note something: if $z$ and $n$ are complex variable then $ \left(e^z\right)^n \neq e^{nz}$ since there is a multiplicity of values, be cautious about it - see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Multivalued_function)

Comment: $n$ is a natural number