# Is there any definition for this series function $f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^s}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, theta-functions

What I am asking for is if there is any theory related to this real series $f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^s}$ and $s\ge 1$.

As far as I know, if $s = 1$, it's a simple geometric series, and if $s = 2$, the series can be converted to one case of Riemann Theta Function. So what if $s$ is generalized to any real number larger than or equal to 1?

Comment: It's analytic continuation is a bit complicated and was discussed in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637584/analytic-continuation-of-phis-sum-n-ge-1-e-ns/3808724#3808724

Comment: @reuns Thank you so much! That's super helpful.