# Compute the value of the integral $\int_1^{\infty} \lfloor x^2 \rfloor e^{-x} \ \mathrm d x $

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I want to compute the value of the integral $$\int_1^{\infty} \lfloor x^2 \rfloor e^{-x} \ \mathrm d x $$

where $\lfloor \  \rfloor$ denotes the floor function.

**My try:**
I split into a series: since $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor = n$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{n} \le x < \sqrt{n+1}$, I get
$$\int_1^{\infty} \lfloor x^2 \rfloor e^{-x} \ \mathrm d x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \int_{\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{n+1}} e^{-x} \ \mathrm d x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n (e^{-\sqrt{n}}-e^{-\sqrt{n+1}})$$

Now I write down the first few terms of the series and write it in another way:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n (e^{-\sqrt{n}}-e^{-\sqrt{n+1}}) = 1 e^{-\sqrt{1}} - 1 e^{-\sqrt{2}} +2 e^{-\sqrt{2}} - 2 e^{-\sqrt{3}} + 3 e^{-\sqrt{3}} - 3 e^{-\sqrt{4}} + \cdots$$
and note that terms cancel. Thus the series is equal to te following limit:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} ( e^{-\sqrt{1}} +  e^{-\sqrt{2}} +  e^{-\sqrt{3}} + \cdots +e^{-\sqrt{n}}) - n e^{-\sqrt{n+1}}$$

And here I get stuck. Maybe I should use some integration by parts, but as $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$ is discountinuous I don't know if I'm allowed to use it.

Comment: You did a good job but I am afraid that a closed form could not exist. The result $1.67040681796633972123962781000840475064032417$ is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287417/find-the-limiting-value-of-s-a-sqrt1a-sqrt2a-sqrt3a-sqrt4/2340926#2340926

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863230/summation-of-sum-n-0-infty-e-sqrt-n?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

I provide a somewhat generalised form of the result you have found. Assume that $f(x)$ is integrable on $[1,\infty)$ with antiderivative $F(x)$ and denote $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)$ by $F(\infty)$. Then we have
\begin{align}
&\int_1^\infty\lfloor x^k\rfloor f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\qquad (k\in\mathbb{N})\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n^{1/k}}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(F(\infty)-F\left(n^{1/k}\right)\right)
\end{align}